# How do I deal with Survivors who are unhappy about fort defense?

Tags: rebuild-3

Some of my Survivors are unhappy because they worry "How will we defend such a large fort?". Is there any way to deal with this directly?

Comment: I think messages like that aren't actually related to a problem, like [the fallout shelter messages](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/232118/106901) They may potentially just indicate decreasing morale.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think having neighbouring Zombies is the trigger for this, try to place Z Traps (Spikes) around your walls, it decreases the number of zombies. On my game, it appears to be working as a morale boost (but there may be another cause)

Answer (score 1):

I Think the best answer is to get more people to defend the fort, the survivors are just unhappy because they are worried they wont be able to defend it.

Comment: I agree, researching sign posts and searchlights to attract more survivors helps stop this notification coming up.